# How to read values from textbox and send sms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

i want to get the text box values for the **" TO "** field and mesasge  **" BODY "**  field in the code

```
 @client.account.sms.messages.create
```

from the view and store it in two variables and send it to the number specified in TO field. I tried using simple_form_for and form_for helpers but don't know how to do this. Still i am new to rails.

```
class SendController < ApplicationController
def sms
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'

          @account_sid = 'hhiasudh993'

          @auth_token = '0293njierjiwef'

          @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)

          @client.account.sms.messages.create( :from => '(954) 740-8336',:to => '+919600760838',:body => 'received the sms')
end
end
```

Comment: Paste app/views/send/sms.html.erb.
Which is Rails version?

Comment: Look in your server log and you should see the parameters coming through into your controller.  You access them like `params[:foo]`, where "foo" is the name of your parameter.